# Update current user's primary blog after creating a blog in wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

I wanted to update the current user's primary blog to the blog created after blog signup on wp-signup.php form. So that the current user's primary blog is set to the blog he had created.

I tried this but its not working,

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog','update_primary_blog',10);

function update_primary_blog() {
global $wpdb;
update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'primary_blog', $wpdb->insert_id );
}
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
add_action('wpmu_new_blog','update_primary_blog',10, 1);
function update_primary_blog($blog_id) {
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'primary_blog', $blog_id);
}
```

more info (and arguments) on the hook:
http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wpmu_new_blog?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/ms-functions.php